# Limit output to 5 items

Tags: linux

`grep -r 'foo' | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'`

I am using this command to replace all items of foo to bar.
However, I want to only replace foo with bar in the first 5 files. Somehow I would need to cut the output of grep to just the first 5 items, or get xargs to only get the first 5 items from the output.

Thanks!

Comment: _"I would need to cut the output of grep to just the first 5 items"_ -- use `head`. Type `man head` on your terminal or read its [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `head` command to limit the output of grep to the first 5 results before passing it to `xargs`.

Here's the modified command:

```
grep -r -l 'foo' | head -n 5 | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

For items 5 to 10,  you can use a combination of `head` and `tail` commands to achieve that.

Here's the command to process items 5 to 10:

```
grep -r -l 'foo' | head -n 10 | tail -n 6 | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

Comment: Thanks, is there also any command to get lets say items 5-10?